# Existence of a non-trivial linear combination of k+1 orthonormal linearly indep. vectors in the left nullpace of a matrix with k columns

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $v_{1}, ..., v_{k+1}$ is a linearly independent, orthonormal set of vectors in $R^{n}$. Prove that for $Y \in R^{n \times k}$ there exists a non-trivial linear combination of these vectors $w$ such that $Y^{T}w = 0$.

I was looking into Proof of Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem (for spectral norm) in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation and couldn't understand this argument.
I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: What can you say about $Y^T v_1$?

Comment: Hmm, a vector consisting of dot products btwn columns of Y and v1 is what comes to my mind